# How do the wheels attach on this trike design?

Tags: tire, wheels, frames, tricycle

How do the wheels attach on this trike design?

Here are the [design drawings](http://www.n55.dk/MANUALS/SPACEFRAMEVEHICLES/DIY.pdf).  If you go to the section titled **Steering Bridge Components** you can see were it should attach.

However it does not show the actual way it is attached.

Here is picture from the drawings of the steering bridge:

[image]

and here is the finished product:

[image]

The wheels are 24 inches with reinforced axels.

Here is an interesting look at [wicycle](https://wicycle.com/products/bike-trailers/diy-high-sides-bike-trailer) using this type of wheel.

They have an "attacher piece as seen in the kit.  One axel, one wheel, and the attacher pieces.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> How do the wheels attach?

The instructions never illustrate how the wheels attach to the frame so all we can do is guess.

Looking at the picture (the vehicle is facing left)
[image: The vehicle is facing left]
The wheel bolts to the steering rack - attaching something like a wheelchair wheel.
The there is a black verticle rod with a black ball on top on each side used to pivot the rack and steer the vehicle.

(The vehicle is facing right)
[image: The vehicle is facing right]
The wheel bolts to the end of the "steering bridge".
The only place I can see to attach a wheel has been marked in the picture above.

It would be wonderful if the instructions had illustrated the arrangement of the axle bolt, washers, and nuts.

Comment: Thanks.  I added an interesting picture of a related diy build in my question.  Although it is side mounted it has an axel than runs the entire width to the other wheel.  So it is a bit different.  Also they have some specialized mount that connects it to the aluminum.

Comment: That's very similar to the method used for attaching trailer wheels on a lot of child-carrying trailers (which don't have a full-width axle like the wicycle you linked). Most of the force when loaded is torsional (ie twisting the tube), which is resisted by having the mount very close to where the horzontal bars brace the end of the tube. For the rear (drive) wheel, which has to withstand the force of pedaling, it looks like the axle is anchored into 3mm aluminum plates (piece FR4a), which are further reinforced by vertical sections of square tube (FR2a).